# fseek is returning -1 in "w" mode and making file blank in C program

Tags: c, file-io, fseek

Here is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("sample.txt", "w");

    if (fp == NULL)
        return 1;

    int error = 0;

    if ((error = fseek(fp, -5, SEEK_END)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error fseek failed: %d\n", error);
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(fp, "%d", 1);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

My sample.txt file:

```
adsfasdfasdfasfasfasfasdfasfasfasfas
asdfasdfasdfasdfasfadsfsadfadsfsafad
```

In the above program fseek return -1 and makes the file blank and same with "w+" mode. The same program works in "r+" correctly. I want to know what is the relation between fseek and file modes in C language? I try to search but I found nothing on the web till now.

Answer (score 3):

The `fopen` modes `"w"` and `"w+"` will delete the content of the fle, if it exists, so that you will have a new file with a length of zero. The mode `"r+"` will not do this, but will keep any existing file content.

All of this is stated in [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) for `fopen`.

If the file has a length of zero, then the function call

```
fseek(fp, -5, SEEK_END)
```

will fail, because there is no such offset.

Also, it is also worth noting that according to [§7.21.9.2 ¶4 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p4), that function call to `fseek` will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). When a file is opened in text mode (as you have done), the only permissible offset for `fseek` is the value `0` or the previous return value of a function call to [`ftell`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell). This is especially a problem on Microsoft Windows, because it uses `\r\n` at the end of every line, which gets translated to `\n` in text mode. However, this is not a problem on POSIX platforms which do not distinguish between text mode and binary mode. POSIX platforms always use `\n` in both modes.

This rule is also mentioned in [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) for `fseek`.

However, in practice, it probably won't be a problem to use `fseek` with a non-zero offset in text mode, as long as you don't jump into the offset between a `\r` and an `\n` character, and if you take into account that on Windows, a `\r\n` line ending counts as two offsets, even though `\r\n` gets translated to `\n` in text mode.

Comment: While my focus was on fseek I completely forgot about `w` and `w+` mode will create new file as soon as it processes `fopen`. You have solved most of my query about this. Still I wanted to know the relation between file mode and `fseek`. Thanks.

Comment: @RakeshSolanki: You can use `fseek` in all `fopen` modes. However, there are certain rules. I have already mentioned one rule in my answer. Another rule is that when a file is opened in update mode (i.e. the mode contains a `+`, such as `"r+"`), then you may have to use `fseek` (or another file positioning function) before writing after a read, and vice versa. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76245752/12149471) for more information on that rule.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `printf("Error fseek failed: %d\n", error);`  with `perror("fseek");` and it'll likely print `fseek: Invalid argument` or similar.

You truncate the file by opening it with `"w"` and they try to go back 5 characters from the end (in an empty file). In a normal file, that can't be done.

When opening it with `"r+"` the content of the file is preserved and seeking backwards from the end 5 steps succeeds (with the content you've shown).

Comment: Yes I caught my mistake. It returns `fseek: Invalid argument'. Thanks.